# sharepoint connection error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have created a web application and site collection on a sharepoint server 2010 which is installed on remote server (Windows Server 2008). Everything is working, except that, when I try to create workflow for this site at Visual Studio 2010, it throws the following exception:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have experienced that some things only work when you connect to the server using the name of the server, not localhost or the IP address.

Try connecting using the name of the server.